# Click count for whatsapp share anchor link in php

Tags: javascript, php, anchor, whatsapp

I am working on books based website where users have option of sharing option by Whatsapp about books .

I just want to count how many times someone share about that particular book on whatsapp.

my code is

```
      <div class='whatsapp'><a href="whatsapp://send?text=https://example.com/profile?bookid=<?php echo $bookid ?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" target="_blank">
                        </a></div>
```

I Dont know how to tackle this ?
thanks in advance .